# ¿Se puede concatenar más de una pseudoclase en una clase?

Tags: html, css, sass

Estoy buscando la manera de concatenar dos pseudoclases en una sola para lograr un dark mode en mi proyecto, pero desconozco como se hace sin el uso de SASS... ¿Podrían asesorarme?

Ejemplo de cómo sería con SASS, (intento de recreación):

```
        &::after{
            content: "";
            display:block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            position:absolute;
            background: #F1F1F1;
            top:0;
            left:unset;
            right:0;
            border-radius: 100px;
            transition: .3s ease all;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0.2);
        
        }
            
            &:active{
                background: orange;
                color: #000;
                &::after{
                    right:0;
                    left:unset;
```

Busco exactamente lo mismo pero sin implementar SASS en mi proyecto, supongo yo que deberia ser más que posible implementarlo

Comment: Por favor agrega toda la rama o el árbol del `&` y tambien su HTML

Comment: Si tienes .clase {  &:active{} } es lo mismo que .clase:active. Es decir reemplazas el & por el padre y así sucesivamente hasta arriba